# Why don't I need to check in the member_of_set if Element and Element1 are different?

Tags: prolog

When using sets, adding an Element to the Set is done like this:

```
add_to_set(Element, [], [Element]).

add_to_set(Element, [Element | Set], [Element | Set]).

add_to_set(Element, [Element1 | Set], [Element1 | NewSet]) :-
  not(Element = Element1),
  add_to_set(Element, Set, NewSet).
```

Now, with this, I thought member_of_set would be like:

```
member_of_set(Element, [Element|_]).

member_of_set(Element, [Element1|Set]) :-
  not(Element = Element1), /* Not necessary */
  member_of_set(Element, Set).
```

This works like a charm, but in this case, `not(Element = Element1)` is not necessary. I can't seem to figure out why. If you ask for more answers from Prolog, won't it backtrack and succeed on the second clause of `member_of_set`?

An if it's not necessary in the `member_of_set`, then why is it necessary in the `add_to_set`?

Please keep in mind that I'm only studying since one month Prolog, so I'm still in some kind of mind switch...

I know that using cut, there's probably better alternatives, but cut shouldn't be used.

Comment: ?? but cut shouldn't be used. cut/fail combination is *necessary* to define negation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's not necessary in the member_of_set

because it doesn't hurt if the list is not a set. Only you will end up - in case you pass a list with repeated elements inside - with multiple solution, but still each solution is valid.

OTOH, add_to_set leads to invalid data if you remove the test:

```
?- add_to_set(1,[],A),add_to_set(1,A,B).
A = B, B = [1] ;
A = [1],
B = [1, 1] ;
false.
```

for a friendly explanation of cuts, and why are necessary in Prolog, see [this page](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node90.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
contains(Element, [Element|_]).

contains(Element, [_|Set]) :-
  contains(Element, Set).
```

You can read this as: "Element is in a Set, if it's the head of that Set, or if it's in the tail of that Set". If you're checking if it's in the tail, there's no need to check if it's equal to the head, except for performance reasons.

Actually, this way, you're not even restricting it to a Set. It's a general contains.